# How to write the constraints for a zk-SNARK circuit

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, rollup, zk-snark, circom

**Need help with defining constraints for a zk-SNARK circuit**
Hi everyone,

I am developing a zk rollup SDK and I need help with defining the constraints for the circuit. I do not have access to a cryptography expert at the moment and I am looking for resources or community members who can help me.

I am using the circomlib library and I have a basic understanding of zk-SNARKs, but I am not sure how to define the constraints for the circuit. My inputs include the following:

1. parentHash
2. sha3Uncles
3. miner
4. stateRoot
5. transactionsRoot
6. receiptsRoot
7. logsBloom
8. difficulty
9. totalDifficulty
10. size
11. number
12. gasLimit
13. gasUsed
14. timestamp
15. extraData
16. mixHash
17. nonce
18. hash
19. transactions[]
20. uncles[]
    If anyone has experience with defining constraints for zk-SNARK circuits and could share some guidance or resources, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Shreyan

i tried reffering to the circuit of other rollups that are using circom for their circuits for example fluidex but i am not able to understand how they wrote such complex circuit and what exactly is happenning inside the circuits.
i need to create a circuit with these inputs and later generate a proof and then verify it for our rollup sdk project.